# Separate queue for Amazon Redshift vacuums

Tags: amazon-redshift, vacuum

I am considering having a separate queue for vacuum queries with concurrency set to 1 in WLM (Workload Management).
Am choosing concurrency 1 because only a single vacuum query can run at any given moment. I am trying to think if there will be any problems in this implementation.

When i run the following query to check how many slots a vacuum query occupies, it is clear that only 1 slot is occupied at any given point of time by any multi stage vacuum query.

```sql
SELECT wlm.query, wlm.slot_count, trim(q.text), queue_start_time, queue_end_time, total_queue_time
FROM stl_wlm_query wlm, stl_querytext q
WHERE wlm.query = q.query
AND text like '%Vacuum my_awesome_table%'
```

ORDER BY queue_start_time DESC;

```
  query  | slot_count |                                     btrim                               |      queue_start_time      |       queue_end_time
---------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------
 1013242 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table integrity check after vacuum execution          | 2018-04-27 16:46:47.90601  | 2018-04-27 16:46:47.90601
 1013237 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table merge (increment: 2 remaining rows: 77234725)   | 2018-04-27 16:46:40.785284 | 2018-04-27 16:46:40.785284
 1013235 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table merge (increment: 1)                            | 2018-04-27 16:46:29.789227 | 2018-04-27 16:46:29.789227
 1013232 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 35 remaining rows: 331972)     | 2018-04-27 16:46:16.978124 | 2018-04-27 16:46:16.978124
 1013231 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 34 remaining rows: 1458914)    | 2018-04-27 16:46:15.059653 | 2018-04-27 16:46:15.059653
 1013229 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 33 remaining rows: 2586321)    | 2018-04-27 16:46:13.641356 | 2018-04-27 16:46:13.641356
 1013228 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 32 remaining rows: 3713038)    | 2018-04-27 16:46:12.233741 | 2018-04-27 16:46:12.233741
 1013227 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 31 remaining rows: 4839275)    | 2018-04-27 16:46:10.838661 | 2018-04-27 16:46:10.838661
 1013226 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 30 remaining rows: 5965341)    | 2018-04-27 16:46:09.421457 | 2018-04-27 16:46:09.421457
 1013225 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 29 remaining rows: 7090572)    | 2018-04-27 16:46:07.93862  | 2018-04-27 16:46:07.93862
 1013224 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 28 remaining rows: 8215908)    | 2018-04-27 16:46:06.441227 | 2018-04-27 16:46:06.441227
 1013223 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 27 remaining rows: 9341191)    | 2018-04-27 16:46:05.009684 | 2018-04-27 16:46:05.009684
 1013222 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 26 remaining rows: 10467621)   | 2018-04-27 16:46:03.54458  | 2018-04-27 16:46:03.54458
 1013221 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 25 remaining rows: 11594203)   | 2018-04-27 16:46:01.998305 | 2018-04-27 16:46:01.998305
 1013218 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 24 remaining rows: 12720513)   | 2018-04-27 16:46:00.528971 | 2018-04-27 16:46:00.528971
 1013217 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 23 remaining rows: 13844984)   | 2018-04-27 16:45:59.071698 | 2018-04-27 16:45:59.071698
 1013216 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 22 remaining rows: 14970941)   | 2018-04-27 16:45:57.596597 | 2018-04-27 16:45:57.596597
 1013215 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 21 remaining rows: 16097323)   | 2018-04-27 16:45:56.253103 | 2018-04-27 16:45:56.253103
 1013214 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 20 remaining rows: 17223270)   | 2018-04-27 16:45:54.634498 | 2018-04-27 16:45:54.634498
 1013213 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 19 remaining rows: 18351994)   | 2018-04-27 16:45:53.265236 | 2018-04-27 16:45:53.265236
 1013212 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 18 remaining rows: 19477834)   | 2018-04-27 16:45:51.741294 | 2018-04-27 16:45:51.741294
 1013211 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 17 remaining rows: 20605101)   | 2018-04-27 16:45:50.338666 | 2018-04-27 16:45:50.338666
 1013210 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 16 remaining rows: 21730370)   | 2018-04-27 16:45:48.698214 | 2018-04-27 16:45:48.698214
 1013209 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 15 remaining rows: 22856152)   | 2018-04-27 16:45:46.27666  | 2018-04-27 16:45:46.27666
 1013208 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 14 remaining rows: 23981990)   | 2018-04-27 16:45:43.603719 | 2018-04-27 16:45:43.603719
 1013206 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 13 remaining rows: 25107349)   | 2018-04-27 16:45:40.848632 | 2018-04-27 16:45:40.848632
 1013205 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 12 remaining rows: 26233207)   | 2018-04-27 16:45:38.097134 | 2018-04-27 16:45:38.097134
 1013204 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 11 remaining rows: 27359056)   | 2018-04-27 16:45:35.316781 | 2018-04-27 16:45:35.316781
 1013203 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 10 remaining rows: 28486363)   | 2018-04-27 16:45:33.815825 | 2018-04-27 16:45:33.815825
 1013202 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 9 remaining rows: 29612051)    | 2018-04-27 16:45:32.262505 | 2018-04-27 16:45:32.262505
 1013201 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 8 remaining rows: 30738238)    | 2018-04-27 16:45:30.867315 | 2018-04-27 16:45:30.867315
 1013200 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 7 remaining rows: 31864515)    | 2018-04-27 16:45:29.476297 | 2018-04-27 16:45:29.476297
 1013197 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 6 remaining rows: 32989591)    | 2018-04-27 16:45:28.023365 | 2018-04-27 16:45:28.023365
 1013196 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 5 remaining rows: 34115286)    | 2018-04-27 16:45:26.607642 | 2018-04-27 16:45:26.607642
 1013195 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 4 remaining rows: 35241021)    | 2018-04-27 16:45:25.179251 | 2018-04-27 16:45:25.179251
 1013194 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 3 remaining rows: 36367702)    | 2018-04-27 16:45:23.167024 | 2018-04-27 16:45:23.167024
 1013193 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 2 remaining rows: 37493086)    | 2018-04-27 16:45:21.550219 | 2018-04-27 16:45:21.550219
 1013192 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table sort (partition: 1)                             | 2018-04-27 16:45:13.472849 | 2018-04-27 16:45:13.472849
 1013188 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table integrity check before vacuum execution         | 2018-04-27 16:45:13.083657 | 2018-04-27 16:45:13.083657
 1008690 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table integrity check after vacuum execution          | 2018-04-27 09:00:23.795686 | 2018-04-27 09:00:23.795686
 1008686 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table merge (increment: 2 remaining rows: 115824559)  | 2018-04-27 09:00:15.527474 | 2018-04-27 09:00:15.527474
 1008680 |          1 | Vacuum my_awesome_table merge (increment: 1)                            | 2018-04-27 09:00:00.946362 | 2018-04-27 09:00:00.946362
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using multiple queues is to stop one set of queries from interfering with another set of queries. Putting your VACUUMs in a separate queue will mean that your other queries will not be impacted by a long-running VACUUM.

A concurrency of 1 is fine for VACUUM.

More important is the amount of memory you give it -- the more the better, but you also don't want to waste that memory while a VACUUM is *not* running.

So, if you are only running VACUUM for a *part* of the day, the queue is wasted for the remaining time. This might not be optimal for your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the insights John. I was thinking on the same lines, your reply confirms my thoughts. Any thoughts on how to weed out the long running vacuum jobs from the path of other shorter queries?

Comment: is it possible to schedule the WLM setup scripts? like set the highest priority for vacuum queue, run the vacuum, then set back to normal mode

Comment: @PratikKhadloya VACUUM is totally under your own control -- you need to issue the commands yourself. So, use `SET query_group TO <vacuum_queue>`, then issue the VACUUM command. The preferable option is to use the normal queues, but run the VACUUM at night when the cluster isn't being used. You can even run the VACUUM with `set wlm_query_slot_count to <num>` to **assign multiple slots** to VACUUM while it runs. This gives it more memory so it should run faster.

Comment: Thanks for the info. We run vacuum 3 times a day as previously running once a day was not sufficient as we update a lot of our tables on an hourly basis.

Comment: Are your tables sorted by time? If so, loading them in time order means you do not need to VACUUM. Similarly, loading in SORT KEY order avoids vacuuming. Details: [Managing Vacuum Times](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/vacuum-managing-vacuum-times.html)